# What is purpose of changing token key name in DjangoRestFramework

Tags: token, django-rest-framework

In DjangoRestFramework you can change keyword in header for token authentification.

From [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)

> Note: If you want to use a different keyword in the header, such as
>   Bearer, simply subclass TokenAuthentication and set the keyword class
>   variable.

What is the purpose of changing default keyword?
I've seen 'Bearer', 'Basic' and a few other variants, but just don't understand the purpose of doing so.
Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 18):

I found how we need to pass the `keyword` to `TokenAuthentication`.

```
class BearerAuthentication(authentication.TokenAuthentication):
    '''
    Simple token based authentication using utvsapitoken.

    Clients should authenticate by passing the token key in the 'Authorization'
    HTTP header, prepended with the string 'Bearer '.  For example:

    Authorization: Bearer 956e252a-513c-48c5-92dd-bfddc364e812
    '''
    keyword = 'Bearer'
```

Then instead of using `authentication.TokenAuthentication` in the `settings.py` we will use `BearerAuthentication`

```
# settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (                                                                                                                                                                                       
        'your.models.BearerAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Comment: Heads up for anyone trying to set the keyword for Session or Basic auth: the header for those two does not check the keyword variable. You will instead need to override the authenticate_header method to return None, or a string of your choice

Comment: the same is mentioned in official documentation. thank you so much for full answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Many web servers support multiple methods of authorization. In those
>   cases sending just the token isn't sufficient.

[Source](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/why-is-bearer-required-before-the-token-in-authorization-header-in-a-http-re)